# Export all data using ngx-export-as in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

I am using "ngx-export-as" package for export mat-table data in excel. I have multiple tables along with mat-paginator in component. it export to excel but it exporting records which are display.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCCch.png)

As seen in image when i click "Excel" Button it export only 5 record but table has total 59 records. i want to export all data of table.

I took reference of [this site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-export-as) but not able to achieve my goal.

i have done some code for this that describe below:
1) In App.module.ts add package

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { ExportAsModule } from 'ngx-export-as';
@NgModule({
    imports: [MaterialModule,ExportAsModule]
});
```

2) gl.Component.html add button & mat-table

```
<div class="row" id="mytable" [style.display]="accordionVisible ?'inherit':'none'">
<button mat-raised-button (click)="exportAs('xlsx')">Excel</button>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let item of accordionAccounts;" >  

  <div [style.display]="accordionVisible && IsDataAvailable(item.DataSource) ?'inherit':'none'">  <!--*ngIf="accordionVisible && item.DataSource.data.length>0"-->
    <br />
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>{{item["AccountName"]}}</mat-panel-title>           
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>  

      <div > 
        <mat-table [dataSource]="item.DataSource">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="RowNumber">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="RowNumberColumn" >No.</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="RowNumber" *matCellDef="let element" class="RowNumberColumn"> {{element.RowNumber}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="DateColumn">Date</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Date" *matCellDef="let element" class="DateColumn"> {{element.Date}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="LeaseName">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="LeaseColumn">Lease Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="LeaseName" *matCellDef="let element" class="LeaseColumn"> {{element.LeaseName}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Account">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="AccountColumn">Account</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Account" *matCellDef="let element" class="AccountColumn"> {{element.AccountName}}</mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="CenterAlign AccountColumn">Description</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Description" class="CenterAlign AccountColumn" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Description}}
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Debit">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="Digit-Cell DebitColumn">Debit</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Debit" class="Digit-Cell DebitColumn" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Debit | number : this.setFormatNumber(this.fraction)}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Credit">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="Digit-Cell CreditColumn">Credit</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Credit" class="Digit-Cell CreditColumn" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Credit | number : this.setFormatNumber(this.fraction)}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Balance">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="Digit-Cell BalanceColumn">Balance</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell data-label="Balance" class="Digit-Cell BalanceColumn" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Balance | number : this.setFormatNumber(this.fraction)}}
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>              
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </mat-table>
        <div [style.display]="accordionVisible && IsDataAvailable(item.DataSource) ?'inherit':'none'" *ngIf="AllowPaggination"> <!--*ngIf="item.DataSource.data.length===0"-->
            <mat-paginator  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons [pageSize]="5" style="justify-content: start"></mat-paginator>
        </div>  
      </div>

    </mat-expansion-panel>

  </div>
</div>
```

3)gl.Component.ts

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA,MatPaginator,MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
import { ExportAsService, ExportAsConfig, SupportedExtensions } from 'ngx-export-as';

export class GLComponent implements OnInit {
 config: ExportAsConfig = {
 type: 'xlsx',
 elementId: 'mytable',
 options: {
   jsPDF: {
     orientation: 'landscape'
   },
   pdfCallbackFn: this.pdfCallbackFn // to add header and footer
 }
};

@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginator = new QueryList<MatPaginator>();

exportAs(type: SupportedExtensions, opt?: string) {

 let that=this;

 this.config.type = type;
 if (opt) {
   this.config.options.jsPDF.orientation = opt;
 }
 this.exportAsService.save(this.config, 'myFile').subscribe(() => {

 });
}

pdfCallbackFn (pdf: any) {
// example to add page number as footer to every page of pdf
const noOfPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
for (let i = 1; i <= noOfPages; i++) {
  pdf.setPage(i);
  pdf.text('Page ' + i + ' of ' + noOfPages, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 100, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 30);
}
```

}

doing this stuff i have export to excel as below :
[Excel Exported with only 5 records.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKrQj.png)

How to get all record of mat-table in angular using "ngx-export-as".
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a dummy html table or a popup that opens up after export button is clicked. Then hit the API that fetches all the 59 records and render it in the new table (or your Mat Table) then give its table id in the ngx-export-as. The library kind of takes a snapshot of current data in html element whose id you've been given so make sure that html element has all the data in place all the time.